# Partially update a session variable in meteor?

Tags: meteor

I think that I might be missing something. I've got the entire contents of a user's product order form stored in a session variable.

```
var orderFormContents = {
  numDoors: 4
  numWheels: 4
  numSeats: 5
};

Session.set("orderFormContentsSessionVar", orderFormContents);
```

How do I update the value of just one key in `orderFormContentsSessionVar`, for instance, just `numDoors`?

I don't want to overwrite the entire existing contents of the session var.

I would love to be able to do something like:

```
Session.set("orderFormContentsSessionVar.numDoors", 2);
```

Something equivalent to `_.extend`

***UPDATE***

Following the example of the answer below, I just wrote a function for it:

```
var updateSession = function(sessionVarName, updateParams){
  var obj = Session.get(sessionVarName);
  _.extend(obj, updateParams);
  Session.set(sessionVarName, obj);
  console.log("updated session name: ", sessionVarName, "new session contents: ", Session.get(sessionVarName));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using like you proposed:

```
var obj = Session.get("orderFormContentSessionVar");
Session.set("orderFormContentsSessionVar", _.extend(obj, {numDoors: 2}));
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured. Thanks. I just wasn't sure if there was some kind of extra property built into Meteor's Session object that allowed for updating out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

`_.extend` should work just fine.

`Session.set( "orderFormContentsSessionVar",
_.extend(Session.get("orderFormContentsSessionVar"), { numSeats: 10 }) )`

I doubt there is any other way.